# Zeppelin Dynamic Form Drop Down value in SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin, dynamic-forms

I have a dropdown element in my Zeppelin notebook

`val instrument = z.select("Select Item", Seq(("A", "1"),("B", "2"),("C", "3")))`

I want to use the value of this variable `instrument` in my sql. For e.g., my next paragraph in the notebook contains

`%sql select * from table_name where item='<<instrument selected above>>'`

Is this possible? If yes, what would the syntax look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is completely possible and here is an example with both `%spark` and `%sql` interpreters :

**cell 1:**

```
val df = Seq((1,2,"A"),(3,4,"B"),(3,2,"B")).toDF("x","y","item")
df.registerTempTable("table_name")
val instrument = z.select("Select Item", Seq(("A", "1"),("B", "2"),("C", "3")))
```

**cell 2:**

```
z.show(df.filter($"item"===instrument))
```

[image: dynamic_spark]

**alternative solution using `%sql`** :

```
%sql select * from table_name where item="${item=A,A|B|C}"
```

[image: dynamic_sql]

PS: `instrument` is set on B,2

Comment: Is there any any specific reason why you use `===` instead of `==` ? Also, I'm trying to understand the difference between `z.show()` and `df.show()`?

Comment: `===` is used to create a column expression which you need to filter on. the `==` returns a boolean. As for df.show() and z.show() it is very clear. z is actually the zeppelin object which you should use to have "those pretty" displays. df.show is just the regular show function of a dataframe.

Comment: `z.show()` is equivalent to Databricks `display()` method, I presume. Your code template does help but I am doing a lot of manipulation to the columns in the sql `select` statement. Hence, I would need a way to use the `instrument` variable in `%sql`

Comment: @Veenit ok here you go !

Comment: `where item="${item=A,A|B|C}" ` does facilitate what I am looking for. Would it be possible to provide label to those values `A, B, C`. For example, I want to display `Item A` in the dropdown but when we select that, `A` should be it's value. I can do this easily through `Seq(("A", "1")` as in my example in the question.

Comment: Also, I would really appreciate if you can share the documentation link (if there is any) surrounding these features in Zeppelin. :-)

Comment: The only documentation that I know about is the official Zeppelin doc but it's quite incomplete. The solution that I have provided is something I've just discovered while using zeppelin. I'm not sure about how you can label your selection in %sql interpreter.

Comment: Do you know how to obtrain %sql result in  %pyspark  interpreter  ?

Answer (score 1):

The other answers haven't really addressed the issue, the syntax you are looking for is:

```
where item = "${Select Item=,1(A)|2(B)|3(C)}"
```

Cheers.