# Select form using the apache zeppelin jdbc (for postgres) interpreter for string field isn't working

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-zeppelin

I'm using the jdbc interpreter for apache zeppelin with a select form for a string field.

This is the implementation i've found online (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38788612) but for the sql interpreter:

```
select * from table where textfield="${choices=choice1,choice1|choice2}"
```

The postgres interpreter documentation says that it is going to be deprecated and to use jdbc instead. But this same query doesn't work with the jdbc interpreter. The error message I get is

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "choice1" doesn't exist
```

I also tried

```
select * from table where textfield=${choices="choice1","choice1"|"choice2"}
```

and

```
select * from table where textfield=${choices=choice1,choice1|choice2}
```

which also didn't work - it throws the same error. The same thing works as expected for integers because there is no problem with quotes there. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just using single quotes fixed the problem